# field not found when Insert / Update with Variable in Pentaho?

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

I want to update the table using some variable, so i set some variable

```
${tab} = table name
${pkey} = primary key column name
${col} = column name.
```

So I set my insert / update like this. the cleansed is field name that the value is gonna replace the value inside column that i set the variable is ${col}

[image]

When I try to run, it come out with this error that the id in stream field is not found.

[image]

the id that not found I've already set it on this table input.

[image]

This is my transformation flow, where the error is on Insert/update 2, and I set the [id] on Data_in_1. and the other Insert/update i use the [id] as a stream field too and therse no problem in it when i try to run it without the insert/update 2.

[image]

this is inside the insert/update which has no error when i use the [id] field as stream field.

[image]

Comment: if you are already replacing it in table input then after that use select values step, and use the column name instead of variable in insert/update.

Comment: soI put the select value is right after the table input, and use the column name insead of the variable but the error is still the same